# Immediately-invoked function expression inside JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on the React project where I am trying to compile but cannot find why I am getting this syntax error.    Specifically, what the pattern, "{()=>{}()}", is doing in this context?

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected } (35:9)

33 |             return (<div className="loading" />);
34 |           } 
35 |         }()}
   |          ^
36 |       </div>
37 |     );
38 |   }

@ ./src/containers/SearchApp.js 7:0-52
@ ./src/containers/App.js
@ ./src/index.js
@ multi ./src/index
```

---

The part of code:

```
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <div className="form-group">
      <input onKeyDown={this.searchEnter.bind(this)} type="text" ref="tag" className="form-control input-lg search-bar" placeholder="Enter the tag..." />
      <button onClick={this.searchClick.bind(this)} type="button" className="btn btn-default search-button">Search!</button>
    </div>
    {()=>{
      if (this.props.status === 'PENDING') {
        return (<div className="loading" />);
      }
    }()}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: looks like someone took an old school IIFE, `function (){...}()` and tried to make it a sexy new arrow IIFE, `()=>{...}()` not knowing that arrow IIFE's must be `(() => {...})()`

Comment: Jaromanda is right the pattern for an inline IIFE is `(()=>{})()`. Keep in mind that what is in the first set of parenthesis will be evaluated, in the case of an IIFE a function. Then the second set of parenthesis will call the function.

Comment: Thank you for your comment...! Adding a wrapping around it resolved the syntax error..! I just begin learning javascript and need to learn so much. I always appreciate your help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is [Immediately-invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

> Error With your code?

You need to wrap the function inside (), Check this:

```
{
   (() => {
      if (this.props.status === 'PENDING') {
         return (<div className="loading" />);
      }
   })()
}
```

> what the pattern, "{()=>{}()}", is doing in this context?

Directly we can't put if/else statement or any other statement inside JSX, so for that we need to create a function and put all the logic inside that.

As per **[DOC](https://react-cn.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html)**:

> if-else statements don't work inside JSX. This is because JSX is just
>   syntactic sugar for function calls and object construction. If a ternary expression isn't robust enough, you can use if statements outside of your JSX to determine which components should be used. Or if you prefer a more "inline" aesthetic, define **immediately-invoked function expressions** inside your JSX.

**Another way of writing the same code:**

```
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <div className="form-group">
                ....   
            </div>
            {this._callFun()}    
        </div>
    )
}

_callFun(){
    if (this.props.status === 'PENDING') {
        return (<div className="loading" />);
    }
}
```

Comment: This was exactly the pattern and modifying the code as you listed resolved the error..! Thank you so much.